# How can i receive data from the form(using html & css) in visualforce page and as well as to insert these information into custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can i receive data from the  form(using html & css) in visualforce page and as well as to insert these information into custom object .I seen previous posts but those are related to other languages,can anyone help me. thanks in advance...

```
<apex:page>

<style type="text/css">
    #wrapper {
        width:450px;
        margin:0 auto;
        font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    legend {
        color:#0481b1;
        font-size:16px;
        padding:0 10px;
        background:#fff;
        -moz-border-radius:4px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(4, 129, 177, 0.5);
        padding:5px 10px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    fieldset {
        border-radius:4px;
        background: #fff; 
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #f9fdff);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #f9fdff);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#fff), to(#f9fdff)); /
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #f9fdff);
        padding:20px;
        border-color:rgba(4, 129, 177, 0.4);
    }
    input,
    textarea {
        color: #373737;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        color: #aaa;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        margin-bottom:15px;

        -moz-border-radius:4px;
        -webkit-border-radius:4px;
        border-radius:4px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }
    input[type="text"],
    input[type="password"]{
        padding: 8px 6px;
        height: 22px;
        width:280px;
    }
    input[type="text"]:focus,
    input[type="password"]:focus {
        background:#f5fcfe;
        text-indent: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        color: #373737;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
        -webkit-transition-property: width, background;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -moz-transition-duration: 400ms;
        -moz-transition-property: width, background;
        -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -o-transition-duration: 400ms;
        -o-transition-property: width, background;
        -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
        width: 380px;

        border-color:#ccc;
        box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(4, 129, 177, 0.5);
        opacity:0.6;
    }
    input[type="submit"]{
        background: #222;
        border: none;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        text-transform:uppercase;
        color: #eee;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 5px 0;
        padding: 5px 22px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-border-radius:4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    textarea {
        padding:3px;
        width:96%;
        height:100px;
    }
    textarea:focus {
        background:#ebf8fd;
        text-indent: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        color: #373737;
        opacity:0.6;
        box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(4, 129, 177, 0.5);
        border-color:#ccc;
    }
    .small {
        line-height:14px;
        font-size:12px;
        color:#999898;
        margin-bottom:3px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Wait List form for Attendee </legend>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" name="first_name" placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Number Of Tickets"/>
                </div>    
                <input type="submit" name="Save" value = "save" />
            </fieldset>    
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: are you using Visualforce page and apex controller?

Comment: yes Ratan, using Visualforce page and apex controller...

Comment: Can you post your apex controller code !!!!

Comment: I haven't implemented controller yet, waiting for better way to implement this,can you give me suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of **CustomObject__c**  object use your object and firstName, lastName use your object fields.

```
<apex:page controller="myController">
    <apex:form>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*your style code*/
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Wait List form for Attendee </legend>
                    <div>
                        <apex:inputField value="{obj.FirstName}" html-placeholder="First Name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <apex:inputField value="{obj.LastName}" html-placeholder="Last Name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <apex:inputField value="{obj.password}" html-placeholder="Password"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <apex:inputField value="{obj.email}" html-placeholder="Email"/>
                    </div>
                    <apex:commandbutton action="{!createRecord}"  />
                </fieldset>   
        </div>
    </body>
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

controller

```
public class myController
{
    public CustomObject__c obj {get;set;}
    public myController()
    {
       obj = new CustomObject__c();

    }
     public PageReference createRecord()
     {
       insert obj;
        return new PageReference('\'+obj.Id);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ratan, i got understand and will try this.thank you...